# How is the Ampyx Power plain generating energy?

Tags: energy-efficiency, wind-power

This is what I'm talking about:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ampyx_Power)
- [Youtube video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lykCHdMNvQM)
- [Youtube video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCHk4TRr5hE)
- [Official site](https://www.ampyxpower.com/technology)

Can you please explain me on how this plane is generating energy? Reeling back the aircraft should consume the energy produced and maybe more, as now you also fight the wind.

Some energy may be from gravity when the plane descends, but I don't see how that will be enough.

Comment: @OlinLathrop The question could be split to a question and an answer. In this case, the links here would serve as improvement to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've pretty much worked it out: when the wind is lower, or when the plane's controls reduce the plane's lift, it drops, and the winch is wound in. Then the lift increases again, and that reels out the winch, which is where the generator sits.

Its generation is therefore very similar system to Kite Power Systems, which is explained in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap_B-9o7uV8)